# How to mange colors for contour map?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot contour maps using Gnuplot.

I tried using the following command,

```
set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10
splot filename u 1:2:3
```

This is the image file I got using those commands.

[image: contout map]

But I want to give a white color scheme when the third column has a maximum value. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There many, many options for palette choice.  Without going into all of them, I suggest you try `set palette cubehelix`
That provides a color range from dark to white. Here is the output from

```
  set palette cubehelix
  test palette
```

[image]